# Angular HostListener key event on whole component or div

Tags: angular

I am trying this code on angular 8:

```
@HostListener('keydown.shift.tab', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(e) {
        // optionally use preventDefault() if your combination
        // triggers other events (moving focus in case of Shift+Tab)
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('shift and tab');
    }
```

This fires the console log but only when my mouse is focusing the input.

My question is...can this not be fired when outside the input, for example when a particular div is focus or component wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try "document:keydown.shift.tab".

Here is a litte stackblitz containing you hostlistener with this litte modification and it worked for me:

https://angular-jpythl.stackblitz.io